# "*" is not a pure selector. How to add styles globally?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, electron

I'm using Nextron. I ran my code successfully but when I opened the window, the `body` tag had a margin of 8px. I opened up the dev tools and changed it successfully but how do I change in my code? If I try to add it any of the module.css file it gives me an error. If I try to make a global.css file it ignores it. How should I configure the window with global styles?

_app.js :

```
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

global.css:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: "SF Pro Text", "SF Pro Icons", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica",
    "Arial", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 20px 60px;
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to get rid of default styles. You can find install instructions on those pages.

As for your import issue, I doubt that anyone could help with the details you've provided. You can update your answer with your styles structure.